# Again, I have 4 graphs on R, different x axis, but similar trend profile. I tried to overlay them but they are not aligned

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, compare, alignment

I was assisted to overlay two graphs with different x-axis on this link [I have 2 graphs on R. They have different x axis, but similar trend profile. how do I overlay them on r?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63467303/13480343).
However, I am now trying to **overlay 4 graphs**. I tried to overlay them but they are not aligned.
I need assistance to overlay these four graphs. [image]

My initial trial codes were as follows:

1. My raw data is in this following link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZZQAATkbeV-Nvq1YYZMYdneZwMvKVUq1?usp=sharing.
2. Codes used to execute:

   ```
   first <- ggplot(data = first,                
                     aes(x, y)) + 
          geom_line(pch = 1)

     second <- ggplot(data = second,                
                     aes(x, y)) + 
          geom_line(pch = 1)

     third <- ggplot(data = third,                
                     aes(x, y)) + 
          geom_line(pch = 1)

     fourth <- ggplot(data = fourth,                
                     aes(x, y)) + 
          geom_line(pch = 1)

    first$match <- first$x
    second$match <- second$x - second$x[second$y == max(second$y)] + first$x[first$y == max(first$y)]
    third$match <- third$x
    fourth$match <- fourth$x
    first$series = "first"
    second$series = "second"
    third$series = "third"
    fourth$series = "fourth"

    all_data <- rbind(first, second, third, fourth)

    ggplot(all_data) + geom_line(aes(x = match, y, color = series)) +
                                   scale_x_continuous(name = "X, arbitrary units") + 
                                   theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
   ```

Would greatly appreciate the help indeed.

Comment: OP, can you post an image of what your plot looks like with the code above?  After a cursory glance, I'm not seeing an obvious issue, but can you explain what you're trying to do with the `second` plot in terms of `second$match`?

Comment: @chemdork123, I attached the picture for reference. I would like the graphs to be aligned like as shown with red and blue coloured curves. I am not sure why I put it there honestly. I would suppose it was meant to solve the curves to align for first and second basically. P.S, I am not a bioinformatician, but I am learning, so if I am wrong in my explanation, I would gladly appreciate the constructive criticism as I am still in my infancy.

Comment: I see:  You're trying to align the peaks in the charts.  Are these part of a time series?  Using a similar method to align your x values for `third` should work, but not for `fourth`, since the max is to the far right on that one.  It's possible to use the `findpeaks()` function from the `pracma` package for that.  I cannot access Google Drive links though, so hard to help with your specific dataset.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZZQAATkbeV-Nvq1YYZMYdneZwMvKVUq1?usp=sharing. Maybe you can try this link? It must work I suppose.

Comment: No, it's not that the particular link didn't work, it's that I literally am unable to access Google Drive links (or other filesharing links) using this computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP, I thought I would propose a solution for your question.  OP has 4 datasets with `x` and `y` columns, and wants to align the peaks in each dataset so that they stack on top of one another.  Here's what it looks like when we plot all datasets together:

```
p <- ggplot(mapping=aes(x=x, y=y)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_line(data=first, aes(color="first")) +
  geom_line(data=second, aes(color="second")) +
  geom_line(data=third, aes(color="third")) +
  geom_line(data=fourth, aes(color="fourth"))
```

[image]

The approach will be as follows:

1. Find the peak x value for each dataset
2. Adjust each peak x value to match that of the first peak x value
3. Combine the datasets and plot together [which respects Tidy Data principles](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html)

## Finding peaks and adjusting x values

To find the peaks, I like to use the `findpeaks()` function from the `pracma` library.  You feed the function your dataset's y values (arranged by increasing x value), and the function will return a matrix with each row representing a "peak" and the columns give you height of peak in y value, *index* or row of dataset for the peak, where the peak begins, and where the peak ends.  As an example, here's how we can apply this principle and what the result looks like on one of the datasets:

```
library(pracma)

first <- arrange(first, x)  # arrange first by increasing x
findpeaks(first$y, sortstr = TRUE, npeaks=1)

        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 1047.54  402  286  515
```

The argument `sortstr=` indicates we want the list of peaks sorted by "highest" first, and we are only interested in picking the first peak.  In this case, we can see that 402 is the index of the x,y value in `first` for the peak.  So we can access that x value via `first[index,]$x`.

The one concern we may have here is that this may not work for `fourth`, since the max value of `y` is actually not the peak of interest; however, if we run the function and test this out, using the `findpeaks()` method where we return the highest peak works fine: apparently the function does not find there is a "peak" at the right since it has an "up", but not a "down".

The function below handles all the steps to do what we need to:  arranging, finding peaks, and adjusting peaks.

```
# find the minimum peak.  We know it's from third, but here's
# how you do it if you don't "know" that

peaks_first <- findpeaks(first$y, sortstr = TRUE, npeaks=1)
peaks_second <- findpeaks(second$y, sortstr = TRUE, npeaks=1)
peaks_third <- findpeaks(third$y, sortstr = TRUE, npeaks=1)
peaks_fourth <- findpeaks(fourth$y, sortstr = TRUE, npeaks=1)

# minimum peak x value
peak_x <- min(c(first[peaks_first[2],]$x, second[peaks_second[2],]$x, third[peaks_third[2],]$x, fourth[peaks_fourth[2],]$x))

# function to use to fix each dataset
fix_x <- function(peak_x, dataset) {
  dataset <- arrange(dataset, x)
  d_peak <- findpeaks(dataset$y, sortstr = TRUE, npeaks=1)
  d_peak_x <- dataset[d_peak[2],]$x
  x_adj <- peak_x - d_peak_x
  dataset$x <- dataset$x + x_adj
  return(dataset)
}

# apply and fix each dataset
fix_first <- fix_x(peak_x, first)
fix_second <- fix_x(peak_x, second)
fix_third <- fix_x(peak_x, third)
fix_fourth <- fix_x(peak_x, fourth)

# combine datasets
fix_first$measure <- 'First'
fix_second$measure <- 'Second'
fix_third$measure <- 'Third'
fix_fourth$measure <- 'Fourth'

fixed <- rbind(fix_first, fix_second, fix_third, fix_fourth)
fixed$measure <- factor(fixed$measure, levels=c('First','Second','Third','Fourth'))
```

## Plot Together

Now `fixed` contains all the data, and we can plot them all together:

```
ggplot(fixed, aes(x=x, y=y, color=measure)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

## Alternate Plotting Methods

If you want to "stack" the lines on top of one another, this is what is known as a ridgeline plot.  There are two methods I can show for how to create the ridgeline plot: faceting or using `ggridges` and `geom_ridgeline()`.  I can demonstrate both.

```
# Using facets
ggplot(fixed, aes(x=x, y=y, color=measure)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_line(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_grid(measure~.)
```

[image]

Note I chose not to show the legend, since the strip text indicates this same information.

```
# Using ggridges and geom_ridgeline
ggplot(fixed, aes(x=x, y=measure, color=measure)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_ridgeline(aes(height=y), fill=NA, scale=0.001)
```

[image]

When using `geom_ridgeline()`, you'll notice that the `y=` aesthetic becomes the column used for the stacking, and your original y value is instead mapped to the `height=` aesthetic.  I also had to play around with `scale=`, since for discrete values, each `measure` will be treated as integers (1, 2, 3, 4).  Your `height=` values are waaaay higher than that, so we have to scale them down so that they are around this range (scaled down by about 1000).

Comment: Wow! Thank you a million @chemdork123, this is the best example of how one can execute the alignments for such spectra data! Thank you once more!