# ggplot2, align plots, multiple data frames

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have quite a complicated situation here. I have plotted graphs for multiple data frames and now I would like to align the graphs (from different time points) on top of each other so that I can calculate the differences in area. I found one example that is quite similar to my case which is [Again, I have 4 graphs on R, different x axis, but similar trend profile. I tried to overlay them but they are not aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63470283/again-i-have-4-graphs-on-r-different-x-axis-but-similar-trend-profile-i-trie) but having some problems incorporating the codes into the one I have.

The codes that I use to produce graphs:

```r
test <- { tibble::tribble(
    ~X, ~well, ~channel,           ~D0_xbl,            ~D2_xbl,
    9.686, "B10",       1L,         -155.8225,   4.00670000000036,
    20.757, "B10",       1L, -42.7895000000001,            88.8957,
    31.827, "B10",       1L,           58.8525,   94.4947000000002,
    42.897, "B10",       1L,          -59.4175, -0.634299999999712,
    53.967, "B10",       1L,          105.7215,   39.6557000000003,
    65.037, "B10",       1L,          -34.3235,   6.55270000000019,
    76.108, "B10",       1L,  62.9155000000001,   48.6517000000003,
    87.178, "B10",       1L, -45.4504999999999,   85.5467000000003,
    98.248, "B10",       1L,         -116.7475,            49.0877,
    109.318, "B10",       1L,           38.4585,   93.4257000000002,
    120.389, "B10",       1L,          -31.1765,           232.1787,
    131.459, "B10",       1L,           29.3515,   70.8517000000002,
    142.529, "B10",       1L, -6.90750000000003,  -4.68329999999969,
    153.599, "B10",       1L, -42.4145000000001,   34.8097000000002,
    164.669, "B10",       1L,          -16.5445,   13.8357000000001,
    175.74, "B10",       1L, -31.2415000000001,   24.4697000000001,
    186.81, "B10",       1L,          160.5085,   73.4697000000001,
    197.88, "B10",       1L,          124.0345,           167.1967,
    208.95, "B10",       1L,  37.4204999999999,  -77.8872999999999,
    220.02, "B10",       1L,           15.3125,   95.1307000000002,
    231.091, "B10",       1L,          146.6605,  -2.10129999999981,
    242.161, "B10",       1L,  74.1445000000001,           102.0707,
    253.231, "B10",       1L,          158.5245,   56.5387000000001,
    264.301, "B10",       1L,  50.0195000000001,  -26.0482999999999,
    275.372, "B10",       1L,  7.28850000000011,   56.8097000000002,
    286.442, "B10",       1L, -50.6834999999999,           133.3877,
    297.512, "B10",       1L, -40.9314999999999,           131.8557,
    308.582, "B10",       1L,  19.0475000000001,   90.3387000000002,
    319.652, "B10",       1L,          141.2015,   67.3967000000002,
    330.723, "B10",       1L,          128.3935,   71.6697000000004,
    341.793, "B10",       1L,  58.1735000000001,           115.6027,
    352.863, "B10",       1L, -13.6924999999999,  -64.8702999999996,
    363.933, "B10",       1L, -83.7294999999999,           106.3647,
    375.003, "B10",       1L,  50.4345000000001,           104.1957,
    386.074, "B10",       1L,  76.1725000000001,           307.6887,
    397.144, "B10",       1L,          101.9985,           774.7727,
    408.214, "B10",       1L,           40.2545,           784.1097,
    419.284, "B10",       1L,  58.5654999999999,           369.1267,
    430.355, "B10",       1L,           50.7165,           385.9197,
    441.425, "B10",       1L,          -16.6785,          1130.5667,
    452.495, "B10",       1L,          133.4325,          1400.3707,
    463.565, "B10",       1L,  72.1055000000001,          1198.9237,
    474.635, "B10",       1L,          139.6325,          1014.3347,
    485.706, "B10",       1L, -3.93450000000007,          1463.5897,
    496.776, "B10",       1L,  68.0595000000001,          1570.4517,
    507.846, "B10",       1L,  11.2235000000001,          2139.4587,
    518.916, "B10",       1L,           93.9655,          2203.3437,
    529.986, "B10",       1L,  36.3745000000001,          1962.2727,
    541.057, "B10",       1L,          456.5205,          1624.9887,
    552.127, "B10",       1L,         1529.5735,          1768.4587,
    563.197, "B10",       1L,         1210.1765,          2609.8267,
    574.267, "B10",       1L,          933.8345,          1952.8747,
    585.338, "B10",       1L,          949.9645,          1694.0647,
    596.408, "B10",       1L,          846.4655,          1967.6097,
    607.478, "B10",       1L,         1287.1835,          2188.6207,
    618.548, "B10",       1L,          810.8085,          2037.5187,
    629.618, "B10",       1L,         1581.2825,          1996.9807,
    640.689, "B10",       1L,         1447.2465,          1895.3097,
    651.759, "B10",       1L,         1150.8545,          2383.5607,
    662.829, "B10",       1L,         1021.3545,          2856.0917,
    673.899, "B10",       1L,         1163.8035,          1695.7227,
    684.969, "B10",       1L,         1036.4985,          1478.2927,
    696.04, "B10",       1L,         1385.2305,          1438.0127,
    707.11, "B10",       1L,         1110.9345,          1767.6497,
    718.18, "B10",       1L,         1236.8995,          1679.9767,
    729.25, "B10",       1L,         1234.2425,          1645.0757,
    740.32, "B10",       1L,         1245.7005,          3204.8157,
    751.391, "B10",       1L,         1300.4695,          2235.8947,
    762.461, "B10",       1L,         1199.7535,          2094.3267,
    773.531, "B10",       1L,         1527.7805,          2632.5457,
    784.601, "B10",       1L,         2143.8785,          2729.5467,
    795.672, "B10",       1L,         2159.5825,          2571.9267,
    806.742, "B10",       1L,         2213.4885,          1312.5767,
    817.812, "B10",       1L,         2042.5345,           975.0967,
    828.882, "B10",       1L,         1314.8645,           966.0137,
    839.952, "B10",       1L,         1451.0225,          1008.0837,
    851.023, "B10",       1L,         1258.2025,          1098.4797,
    862.093, "B10",       1L,         1121.5705,          1069.2367,
    873.163, "B10",       1L,         1204.0055,          1583.8107,
    884.233, "B10",       1L,          815.5735,           846.2797,
    895.303, "B10",       1L,          967.7465,           692.1867,
    906.374, "B10",       1L,          658.2835,           565.0897,
    917.444, "B10",       1L,          707.9115,           576.5227,
    928.514, "B10",       1L,          879.8085,           424.1697,
    939.584, "B10",       1L,          845.4505,           186.8957,
    950.655, "B10",       1L,          469.9845,           355.6597,
    961.725, "B10",       1L,          630.6155,           607.0667,
    972.795, "B10",       1L,          845.0745,           343.0777,
    983.865, "B10",       1L,          815.6185,           164.8487,
    994.935, "B10",       1L,          789.0455,           206.8607,
    1006.006, "B10",       1L,          352.6235,   4.21470000000045,
    1017.076, "B10",       1L,          -39.6215,  -96.3862999999997,
    1028.146, "B10",       1L,           54.3235,   42.2237000000005,
    1039.216, "B10",       1L, -16.6444999999999,           207.2787,
    1050.286, "B10",       1L, -85.5305000000001,   91.4667000000004,
    1061.357, "B10",       1L,          124.1915,           -16.8453,
    1072.427, "B10",       1L,  38.2495000000001,  -80.7472999999995,
    1083.497, "B10",       1L,          136.5115,   76.3807000000002,
    1094.567, "B10",       1L,          106.3755,   48.1157000000003,
    1105.637, "B10",       1L,          126.8225,   63.3017000000004,
    1116.708, "B10",       1L,           68.3335,   89.4927000000002,
    1127.778, "B10",       1L,          -61.2335,           111.2477,
    1138.848, "B10",       1L,  42.6435000000001,  -71.4192999999996,
    1149.918, "B10",       1L,           53.7655,           -20.3543,
    1160.989, "B10",       1L,          -35.1665,   67.8217000000004,
    1172.059, "B10",       1L,           52.5805,           159.1147,
    1183.129, "B10",       1L,          111.1855,   22.9657000000002,
    1194.199, "B10",       1L,          -24.1955,           112.1027,
    1205.269, "B10",       1L,  54.5115000000001,  -41.0972999999999,
    1216.34, "B10",       1L, -43.0964999999999,  -19.1202999999996,
    1227.41, "B10",       1L, -52.5205000000001,  -97.8572999999997,
    1238.48, "B10",       1L,  43.9404999999999,   7.71270000000004,
    1249.55, "B10",       1L,  49.2135000000001,   34.3027000000002,
    1260.62, "B10",       1L, -2.48049999999989,          -114.3783,
    1271.691, "B10",       1L,  7.28549999999996,  -10.5312999999996,
    1282.761, "B10",       1L, -42.7584999999999,   60.6557000000003,
    1293.831, "B10",       1L,  46.0084999999999,  -65.6582999999996,
    1304.901, "B10",       1L,  46.2615000000001,  -3.21529999999984,
    1315.972, "B10",       1L,  79.4984999999999,  -89.1422999999995,
    1327.042, "B10",       1L, -37.2404999999999,   -2.9712999999997,
    1338.112, "B10",       1L,          -62.6095,           -45.7873,
    1349.182, "B10",       1L,          170.1795,  -88.3102999999996,
    1360.252, "B10",       1L,           81.1495, -0.548299999999927,
    1371.323, "B10",       1L,  40.6845000000001,          -119.4453,
    1382.393, "B10",       1L,          -59.4195,  -87.3212999999996,
    1393.463, "B10",       1L,         -101.7965,  -23.7672999999995,
    1404.533, "B10",       1L, -67.6524999999999,          -145.1293,
    1415.604, "B10",       1L, -69.9065000000001,  -8.45029999999997,
    9.686, "B10",       2L,           32.8377,   58.2847999999999,
    20.757, "B10",       2L, -33.1342999999999,            64.5018,
    31.827, "B10",       2L,          -61.1333,   34.1397999999999,
    42.897, "B10",       2L,           10.6267,  -20.0412000000001,
    53.967, "B10",       2L, -90.9373000000001,            80.5778,
    65.037, "B10",       2L,  16.2587000000001,           -79.0942,
    76.108, "B10",       2L,          -16.4213,           114.7918,
    87.178, "B10",       2L,  39.1506999999999,           176.3198,
    98.248, "B10",       2L, -56.9083000000001,           120.6258,
    109.318, "B10",       2L, -56.8172999999999,           231.3008,
    120.389, "B10",       2L,          -39.2763,           118.9998,
    131.459, "B10",       2L,  37.7197000000001,           188.1798,
    142.529, "B10",       2L,  29.4897000000001,           159.5898,
    153.599, "B10",       2L,           90.6547,           212.2138,
    164.669, "B10",       2L,  82.3157000000001,   48.2748000000001,
    175.74, "B10",       2L,          -13.5823,           100.5768,
    186.81, "B10",       2L,  37.2187000000001,   68.1527999999998,
    197.88, "B10",       2L,  19.8557000000001,            98.6088,
    208.95, "B10",       2L,          -10.9003,   66.9947999999999,
    220.02, "B10",       2L,  66.3747000000001,           215.0338,
    231.091, "B10",       2L,          120.1917,   91.3827999999999,
    242.161, "B10",       2L,          147.0387,           220.1298,
    253.231, "B10",       2L,           47.6357,           101.9528,
    264.301, "B10",       2L,  50.7936999999999,           150.2908,
    275.372, "B10",       2L,          130.0087,           141.7358,
    286.442, "B10",       2L,          117.5957,   14.7618000000002,
    297.512, "B10",       2L,          160.6267,           110.8018,
    308.582, "B10",       2L,          135.7857,   60.9598000000001,
    319.652, "B10",       2L,          202.0947,   81.4958000000001,
    330.723, "B10",       2L,           68.9557,           120.7128,
    341.793, "B10",       2L,          169.1917,           308.4068,
    352.863, "B10",       2L,          113.2727,           269.6688,
    363.933, "B10",       2L,          109.6227,           461.7048,
    375.003, "B10",       2L,          129.7987,          1053.1878,
    386.074, "B10",       2L,          115.9467,          1064.7468,
    397.144, "B10",       2L,          200.9837,          1579.6108,
    408.214, "B10",       2L,          191.3437,          2172.2458,
    419.284, "B10",       2L,          226.0057,          2944.0758,
    430.355, "B10",       2L,          124.2177,          4546.9178,
    441.425, "B10",       2L,          158.6067,          5477.1518,
    452.495, "B10",       2L,          158.1067,          6558.3688,
    463.565, "B10",       2L,          199.9537,          9359.9058,
    474.635, "B10",       2L,          248.4207,          8955.4778,
    485.706, "B10",       2L,  90.5937000000001,          8688.8828,
    496.776, "B10",       2L,          207.5587,         10080.7118,
    507.846, "B10",       2L,          311.4657,         10275.0288,
    518.916, "B10",       2L,          467.0877,         10433.3588,
    529.986, "B10",       2L,          905.3517,         12209.0968,
    541.057, "B10",       2L,         2489.9817,         12865.1098,
    552.127, "B10",       2L,         2713.0927,         13218.6738,
    563.197, "B10",       2L,         3641.7787,         13239.0058,
    574.267, "B10",       2L,         5182.9527,         15322.5888,
    585.338, "B10",       2L,         5974.6247,         16156.5168,
    596.408, "B10",       2L,         5780.4457,         17103.6088,
    607.478, "B10",       2L,         7767.7557,         16813.8368,
    618.548, "B10",       2L,         8072.3497,         17356.2178,
    629.618, "B10",       2L,         8105.3237,         16824.5738,
    640.689, "B10",       2L,         9144.0957,         16418.7338,
    651.759, "B10",       2L,         9357.9307,         14780.2238,
    662.829, "B10",       2L,         9004.6337,         14720.4408,
    673.899, "B10",       2L,         9278.8677,         14716.7318,
    684.969, "B10",       2L,         8826.8647,         15267.6398,
    696.04, "B10",       2L,         9460.4607,         15704.1598,
    707.11, "B10",       2L,        10086.5107,         14377.4528,
    718.18, "B10",       2L,        10550.7447,         14378.8668,
    729.25, "B10",       2L,        10727.4867,         14163.1128,
    740.32, "B10",       2L,        10328.1397,         13898.6988,
    751.391, "B10",       2L,         9588.1967,         15137.3628,
    762.461, "B10",       2L,         9802.8557,         15382.4588,
    773.531, "B10",       2L,         9969.1387,         14017.4518,
    784.601, "B10",       2L,         9773.0927,         14366.7458,
    795.672, "B10",       2L,        10843.1557,         14402.6658,
    806.742, "B10",       2L,         9507.3317,         13536.5758,
    817.812, "B10",       2L,         9635.2037,         13916.1358,
    828.882, "B10",       2L,         9201.7927,         14168.7938,
    839.952, "B10",       2L,         8951.5947,         13464.2448,
    851.023, "B10",       2L,         9392.3187,         11628.7788,
    862.093, "B10",       2L,         9370.3957,          9905.5898,
    873.163, "B10",       2L,         8725.5897,          8986.6368,
    884.233, "B10",       2L,         8434.9267,          9949.8578,
    895.303, "B10",       2L,         8837.1217,          7313.6318,
    906.374, "B10",       2L,         8419.9807,          5571.4098,
    917.444, "B10",       2L,         7391.0737,          4657.6828,
    928.514, "B10",       2L,         6714.7317,          4098.5498,
    939.584, "B10",       2L,         5782.0777,          2538.7008,
    950.655, "B10",       2L,         5413.3007,          1490.7858,
    961.725, "B10",       2L,         3750.3557,          1208.7628,
    972.795, "B10",       2L,         4115.5457,          1139.1798,
    983.865, "B10",       2L,         3101.5787,           986.7688,
    994.935, "B10",       2L,         2155.4357,          1138.8178,
    1006.006, "B10",       2L,          597.6727,           500.2128,
    1017.076, "B10",       2L,          254.3607,           272.2878,
    1028.146, "B10",       2L,          191.4137,           502.7578,
    1039.216, "B10",       2L,          227.2307,           283.7788,
    1050.286, "B10",       2L,          176.0657,           189.7588,
    1061.357, "B10",       2L,          185.4807,           181.5548,
    1072.427, "B10",       2L,          204.4357,           243.3478,
    1083.497, "B10",       2L,          154.3877,   14.6208000000001,
    1094.567, "B10",       2L,          130.7767,           216.9358,
    1105.637, "B10",       2L,          146.7777,   74.8618000000001,
    1116.708, "B10",       2L,           40.3987,           160.9298,
    1127.778, "B10",       2L,          172.7047,           120.1748,
    1138.848, "B10",       2L,          222.7767,  -23.3002000000001,
    1149.918, "B10",       2L,          213.2867,            65.1558,
    1160.989, "B10",       2L,  77.7466999999999,   99.0098000000003,
    1172.059, "B10",       2L,          153.4467,   46.0518000000002,
    1183.129, "B10",       2L,          128.7027,           124.2868,
    1194.199, "B10",       2L,  79.1886999999999,   27.0057999999999,
    1205.269, "B10",       2L,  87.0256999999999,           191.3108,
    1216.34, "B10",       2L,  12.1637000000001,   39.4338000000002,
    1227.41, "B10",       2L,          120.3677,           105.2318,
    1238.48, "B10",       2L,  65.2166999999999,           129.2918,
    1249.55, "B10",       2L,           21.2227,           136.6078,
    1260.62, "B10",       2L,          114.4567,           170.6008,
    1271.691, "B10",       2L,  83.4797000000001,  -54.1711999999998,
    1282.761, "B10",       2L,          105.9617,  -37.3982000000001,
    1293.831, "B10",       2L, -25.8172999999999,          -136.0802,
    1304.901, "B10",       2L,          134.7887,  -50.3222000000001,
    1315.972, "B10",       2L,          141.5367,           111.9678,
    1327.042, "B10",       2L,           63.1767,   11.5837999999999,
    1338.112, "B10",       2L,          -15.9893,  -19.4771999999998,
    1349.182, "B10",       2L,  25.7597000000001,  -13.9061999999999,
    1360.252, "B10",       2L, -1.01929999999993,           125.2698,
    1371.323, "B10",       2L,           53.0797,            59.4238,
    1382.393, "B10",       2L,           48.5417,   68.2298000000001,
    1393.463, "B10",       2L, -4.98329999999987,  -45.3472000000002,
    1404.533, "B10",       2L,           22.1477,           121.1538,
    1415.604, "B10",       2L, -18.9032999999999,           -29.3822,
    8.303,  "B3",       1L,          181.2689,   60.0478000000003,
    19.373,  "B3",       1L, -38.1571000000001,   48.8338000000003,
    30.443,  "B3",       1L,         -121.2631,           102.3118,
    41.513,  "B3",       1L,          -24.7701,  -26.4121999999998,
    52.584,  "B3",       1L,  18.7828999999999,   71.6867999999999,
    63.654,  "B3",       1L, -38.3571000000002,  -44.6581999999999,
    74.724,  "B3",       1L,           15.5989,   16.2978000000003,
    85.794,  "B3",       1L,           72.1459,           190.0938,
    96.864,  "B3",       1L,  86.4958999999999,   43.7678000000001,
    107.935,  "B3",       1L,  72.6608999999999,   62.5608000000002,
    119.005,  "B3",       1L, -4.78710000000001,           100.3938,
    130.075,  "B3",       1L,  93.8348999999998,   18.2508000000003,
    141.145,  "B3",       1L,  19.6868999999999,   77.7678000000001,
    152.215,  "B3",       1L,          151.5249,           142.6158,
    163.286,  "B3",       1L,  34.7958999999998,           174.2508,
    174.356,  "B3",       1L,           44.9539,   58.7218000000003,
    185.426,  "B3",       1L,          106.2339,   50.7218000000003,
    196.496,  "B3",       1L, -52.3111000000001,   97.7168000000001,
    207.566,  "B3",       1L,           43.3379,           130.2798,
    218.637,  "B3",       1L, -20.6001000000001,   46.7388000000001,
    229.707,  "B3",       1L, -1.71109999999999,           223.6748,
    240.777,  "B3",       1L,            8.3279,           116.4228,
    251.847,  "B3",       1L,           39.9819,           302.7348,
    262.918,  "B3",       1L,          155.0789,           299.3048,
    273.988,  "B3",       1L,           90.6149,           549.7468,
    285.058,  "B3",       1L, -51.5031000000001,           321.4318,
    296.128,  "B3",       1L,  85.4398999999999,           326.1958,
    307.198,  "B3",       1L,  7.33489999999983,           653.4718,
    318.269,  "B3",       1L,  87.1218999999999,           633.5128,
    329.339,  "B3",       1L,  75.5628999999999,           620.5188,
    340.409,  "B3",       1L,  12.6208999999999,           578.8028,
    351.479,  "B3",       1L,           64.8469,           964.6008,
    362.549,  "B3",       1L,           17.1739,          1778.9198,
    373.62,  "B3",       1L, -12.8011000000001,          2507.6148,
    384.69,  "B3",       1L,  67.4288999999999,          2573.4578,
    395.76,  "B3",       1L,           25.9819,          3531.7628,
    406.83,  "B3",       1L,  74.5538999999999,          4718.6688,
    417.901,  "B3",       1L,           14.7599,          5506.4748,
    428.971,  "B3",       1L,           46.2219,          6261.3468,
    440.041,  "B3",       1L,           91.1749,          6641.3208,
    451.111,  "B3",       1L,  78.0618999999999,          7088.2808,
    462.181,  "B3",       1L,          362.5329,          7686.4378,
    473.252,  "B3",       1L,          683.0009,          9252.7328,
    484.322,  "B3",       1L,         1422.6859,         10571.5488,
    495.392,  "B3",       1L,         3312.6259,         12203.5338,
    506.462,  "B3",       1L,         4541.8399,         12694.5568,
    517.532,  "B3",       1L,         5243.3069,         13057.5618,
    528.603,  "B3",       1L,         5845.7259,         14636.4908,
    539.673,  "B3",       1L,         7102.9149,         16055.8558,
    550.743,  "B3",       1L,         7120.3769,         15317.7138,
    561.813,  "B3",       1L,         7487.3209,         17333.8698,
    572.883,  "B3",       1L,         7563.7669,         19009.7368,
    583.954,  "B3",       1L,         8194.1199,         19128.2208,
    595.024,  "B3",       1L,         8957.9569,         18274.1278,
    606.094,  "B3",       1L,         9747.9479,         18617.6358,
    617.164,  "B3",       1L,        10230.3359,         18361.6428,
    628.235,  "B3",       1L,        10175.5239,         17568.0628,
    639.305,  "B3",       1L,        11451.8879,         17913.1858,
    650.375,  "B3",       1L,        11817.6449,         18396.9968,
    661.445,  "B3",       1L,        11644.8329,         18746.9288,
    672.515,  "B3",       1L,        12268.6839,         18044.6818,
    683.586,  "B3",       1L,        11366.0069,         17464.8478,
    694.656,  "B3",       1L,        11463.3709,         18097.4558,
    705.726,  "B3",       1L,        11707.5339,         17699.1338,
    716.796,  "B3",       1L,        12213.8299,         16750.1298,
    727.867,  "B3",       1L,        12736.1929,         17533.0028,
    738.937,  "B3",       1L,        11905.3129,         15518.7998,
    750.007,  "B3",       1L,        11090.6339,         15338.9358,
    761.077,  "B3",       1L,        11389.0589,         15380.0318,
    772.147,  "B3",       1L,        11647.7379,         15675.0548,
    783.218,  "B3",       1L,        11282.5669,         16118.4168,
    794.288,  "B3",       1L,        10938.0509,         13844.7888,
    805.358,  "B3",       1L,        10122.8809,         13359.2238,
    816.428,  "B3",       1L,         9545.4309,         13025.6378,
    827.498,  "B3",       1L,         8425.0509,         11399.0868,
    838.569,  "B3",       1L,         8079.1629,         10556.0848,
    849.639,  "B3",       1L,         7636.3579,          8793.4578,
    860.709,  "B3",       1L,         6815.7759,          6752.3778,
    871.779,  "B3",       1L,         5946.2199,          6594.9078,
    882.849,  "B3",       1L,         4956.9729,          5291.1728,
    893.92,  "B3",       1L,         4383.4669,          5373.5128,
    904.99,  "B3",       1L,         3234.3959,          4134.4878,
    916.06,  "B3",       1L,         1783.3959,          2922.8588,
    927.13,  "B3",       1L,          380.0739,          2476.4528,
    938.201,  "B3",       1L,          311.5419,          2593.2308,
    949.271,  "B3",       1L,          113.1429,          2318.2268,
    960.341,  "B3",       1L,          196.9929,          1951.3948,
    971.411,  "B3",       1L,          253.6579,          1930.0238,
    982.481,  "B3",       1L,          183.2229,          1301.4458,
    993.552,  "B3",       1L,          176.3239,           874.2718,
    1004.622,  "B3",       1L,           32.8069,           460.3868,
    1015.692,  "B3",       1L,          123.8069,           424.9028,
    1026.762,  "B3",       1L,           94.9729,           529.0918,
    1037.832,  "B3",       1L,  80.8898999999999,           158.8838,
    1048.903,  "B3",       1L,          159.4869,           331.0288,
    1059.973,  "B3",       1L,           66.7019,           354.8768,
    1071.043,  "B3",       1L,  82.0128999999999,           216.2888,
    1082.113,  "B3",       1L, -17.3681000000001,           566.9668,
    1093.183,  "B3",       1L, -3.30010000000016,           258.0708,
    1104.254,  "B3",       1L,           41.8769,           272.4608,
    1115.324,  "B3",       1L, -35.3581000000001,           353.4208,
    1126.394,  "B3",       1L,          146.3999,           160.8448,
    1137.464,  "B3",       1L,  31.7738999999999,           116.4068,
    1148.535,  "B3",       1L,           98.4539,           132.8718,
    1159.605,  "B3",       1L,          129.2769,           194.9508,
    1170.675,  "B3",       1L,           65.5009,            32.5708,
    1181.745,  "B3",       1L,          103.9029,           101.6448,
    1192.815,  "B3",       1L,  66.7538999999999,           158.0018,
    1203.886,  "B3",       1L,           21.6559,           132.5638,
    1214.956,  "B3",       1L,           32.7779,   99.4567999999999,
    1226.026,  "B3",       1L,  75.2438999999999,           102.6528,
    1237.096,  "B3",       1L, -3.24710000000005,            99.1088,
    1248.167,  "B3",       1L,  66.9458999999999,           158.6808,
    1259.237,  "B3",       1L,           51.1239,  0.556800000000294,
    1270.307,  "B3",       1L,           86.7999,           233.1948,
    1281.377,  "B3",       1L,  72.9568999999999,            55.3368,
    1292.447,  "B3",       1L, -22.8971000000001,   72.8468000000003,
    1303.518,  "B3",       1L,  12.4219000000001,           -79.8912,
    1314.588,  "B3",       1L,          153.3359,   2.94680000000017,
    1325.658,  "B3",       1L,  58.8808999999999,   66.2298000000001,
    1336.728,  "B3",       1L,  52.7268999999999,   52.4018000000001,
    1347.798,  "B3",       1L,          139.8269,   86.9678000000004,
    1358.869,  "B3",       1L,  89.9478999999999,   83.9048000000003,
    1369.939,  "B3",       1L,          154.4319,           120.0268,
    1381.009,  "B3",       1L,          148.3779,  -14.7981999999997,
    1392.079,  "B3",       1L,          108.0579,           -46.4422,
    1403.15,  "B3",       1L,  82.3928999999998,   20.2648000000004,
    1414.22,  "B3",       1L,  45.4388999999999,          -136.3362
  )}
test$channel <- as.character(test$channel)
```

```r
library(tidyverse)
save_plot2 <- function(graph, graph_name, type=""){
  if(type !="")
    graph_name <- names(dfs_by_well)
  graph_name <- paste0(graph_name, type)
  filename <- paste0(graph_name, ".tiff")
  filename <- file.path("L:/Lab_GlenB/Mei Fong/test", filename)
  ggsave(filename, graph, device = "tiff")
}  
list_of_dfs_test = test %>% bind_rows()
dfs_by_well <- split(list_of_dfs_test, list_of_dfs_test$well)

purrr::imap(dfs_by_well, function(DF, graph_name) {
 
  graph <- DF %>%
  ggplot(aes(X, colour = channel)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = D0_xbl)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = D2_xbl)) +
  scale_colour_manual(
    name = NULL,
    values = c("#215968", "#C9C400"),
    breaks = c("1", "2"),
    labels = c("GFP", "mCherry")
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(.95, .95),
    legend.justification = c("right", "top")
  ) +
  ggtitle(graph_name) +
  labs(
    x = element_blank(),
    y = "Fluorescence intensity"
    )
  # graph
  save_plot2(graph, graph_name)
})
```

Examples of my graphs:

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

Condition of my data:

1. Multiple data frames where there are 3 time points for each data frame.
2. Some data frames have 1 channel (Example 1), some data frames have 2 channels (Example 2).

The goal is to plot each data frames with aligned plots so that I can calculate the differences between time points. The previous example aligns the plots to the peak, however I don't think is possible for my case. I am thinking align to the median (of the width)?

Really appreciate if someone can help!!

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? https://reprex.tidyverse.org

Comment: Hi @Olivier3213, I've edited the post, is that what you are asking for?

Comment: Ideally, it would have the a data sample included and the packages used. ```r library(tidyverse)    all_dfs_xbf <- list(x1 = data.frame(x = c(1, 2), y = c(2, 3), well = c(4, 5), d2 = data.frame(x = 3, y = 3, well = 4)) ```

Comment: If you have access to the original data, wouldn't it be easier to figure out the variances from that? If your x axis points don't align, you could use `approx` to interpolate them.

Comment: I would like to share the raw data but I have a bit of difficulties here. I have multiple data frames, each has 6 columns and 990 rows for single channel or 1980 for 2 channels. Any ideas how should I do it?

Comment: Hi! @olivroy I've updated the post with a set of test data which I tried with the codes and it works. I manage to level the baseline so now it just to align the graphs. Thanks heaps!

Comment: @JonSpring, do you mind to elaborate more? I m still pretty new in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to get the graphs that I need with a simpler than expected method.

First, I set a threshold so that all the baselines will be removed. Then, from there I find median. Next, I minus median with X to get new x-axis so that all the graphs will have x = 0 as midpoint then plot the graphs.

```
dfs_D0 <- mutate(D0_median = median(X[D0_xbl>1500])) %>%
  transform (D0_x = X-D0_median)
dfs_D2 <- mutate(D2_median = median(X[D2_xbl>1500])) %>%
  transform (D2_x = X-D2_median)
dfs_D4 <- mutate(D4_median = median(X[D4_xbl>1500])) %>%
  transform (D4_x = X-D4_median)
all_dfs <- reduce(list(dfs_D0, dfs_D2, dfs_D4), left_join, by = c("X", "id", "set")) %>%
  separate(id, c("prefix", "channel", "well", "csv"), 
           sep="[[:punct:]]") %>%
  select(well, set, channel, D0_x, D0_xbl, D0_mean_sd, D2_x, D2_xbl, D2_mean_sd, D4_x, D4_xbl, D4_mean_sd)
```

Then use the same code above to plot the graphs. Editing the x-axis is way easier than keep thinking how to overlay the graphs on top of each other. However, if anyone has any other idea, please let me know too. Thanks!